# Using NPM packages in NEST JS which doesnt have Nest specific package

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, sharp, jimp

In my Nest js app, i want to add libraries which doesnt have any nest specific implementation.
For example sharp or jimp.

I have added these in my project like

```
npm i jimp.
```

and imported in my code like this.

```
import Jimp from 'jimp';
```

It works fine when i build and serve locally, but when i serve it from docker and build production version, i get the following error :

```
> planiac@0.0.0 serve /app
backend_1  | > node dist/apps/api/main.js
backend_1  | 
backend_1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965
backend_1  |   throw err;
backend_1  |   ^
backend_1  | 
backend_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'jimp'
backend_1  | Require stack:
backend_1  | - /app/dist/apps/api/main.js
backend_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:15)
backend_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:27)
backend_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
backend_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
backend_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:2687:18)
backend_1  |     at __webpack_require__ (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:20:30)
backend_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1874:62)
backend_1  |     at __webpack_require__ (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:20:30)
backend_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:3423:73)
backend_1  |     at __webpack_require__ (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:20:30) {
backend_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
backend_1  |   requireStack: [ '/app/dist/apps/api/main.js' ]
backend_1  | }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of import

```
const jimp = reuire("jimp")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Docker, it looks like `jimp` is not loaded in your `node_modules`. Try running `npm i jimp` with the `--save` option, so that the package is saved into `package-lock.json`, and make sure your Docker build runs `npm install` (which it probably already does since you are using Nest)

Answer (score 0):

When you just have the require, like padmakar stated, you won't have the types included.
If you want to have type intellisense:

```js
import { default as jimpi } from 'jimp';
const Jimp = require('jimp') as typeof jimpi;
```